# Как в JS переменную записать JSON файл?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

есть файл `cakes.json` и в его содержание:

```
 {
  "cake": [ 
    {"title":"Cake1","price": "cake price","description":"cake price"},
    {"title":"Cake2","price": "cake price","description":"cake price"},
  ]
};
```

Нужно записать его в переменную `var cakes`

Чтобы при вызове `alert(cakes.cake[1].title);`

выводилось название первого cake из файла `cakes.json`

Пробовал манипуляции `$.getJSON('js/test.json', function(data)`

но не получилось.

Comment: у вас ошибка в `json` после второго объекта после `"cake price"}` не должно быть запятой..... и в .`$.getJSON('js/test.json'` должно же быть `cakes.json` ?)). .......и допишите всю функцию `getJSON` вместе с вашим колбэком

Comment: Вставьте ваш `json` вот сюда http://json.parser.online.fr/  и вы увидите что он сломается...... или даже напишите в консоли `JSON.parse(ВАША_СТРОКА_JSON);` и вам тоже выдаст ошибку..............   
точки с запятой тоже не должно быть в конце

Comment: точку с запятой в конце убрал, но запятая перед ключем "description" не является ошибкой https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Comment: Я не говорил про `перед ключом description`..... я говорил `после второго объекта после cake price`..... то есть  после строчки с объектом `{"title":"Cake2","price": "cake price","description":"cake price"}` не должно быть запятой. так как после неё больше нет ничего

Comment: проще говоря: запятая перед `]` - это ошибка

Comment: Судя по неудачному getJSON, есть подозрение что это опять проблема с асинхронностью :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно первый элемент то можно сделать так

```
var json = {
  "cake": [ 
    {"title":"Cake1","price":"cake price","description":"cake price"},
    {"title":"Cake2","price":"cake price","description":"cake price"}
  ]
};
console.log(json.cake[0].title)
```

но по хорошему надо понимать что именно нужно чтобы сказать как это сделать